# running visual studio release build .exe file in different machines

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, build

[image]I have built a visual studio c++ console application(x64 release build). The .exe file in the release folder runs fine with the required dlls. 
When i try to run it on other machine it throws error

> The Application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application

There is no x86-x64 lib mismatch issues.

In another machine it works well.I don't know whether it needs any resource to run the .exe

I have tried building the application  statically still no results..

Comment: Is that the exact error text? I have a hard time imagining grammatically incorrect English in a Microsoft error message.

Comment: Consider opening the binary file on the build machine and on the target machine, using Dependency Walker. The difference between the two outputs should show you the conflict or missing dependency.

Comment: Did you copy all the files under the bin folder or only the exe? Do you have VS installed on the 2 other machines? In case the it does not exist on the machine on which it fails to run it is possible that your application depends on VS redistributable DLLs which are missing

Comment: @utnapistim added the screenshot of dependency walker results.

Comment: @AmnonShochot is this necessary the target machine should have visual studio ?

Comment: Generally not. However, some projects in VS has dependencies on VS redistributables. These are either installed with VS or can be installed separately (see http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784).

Comment: @AmnonShochot tried installing the c++ redistribution packages still the same error.

Comment: @user1992200 okay, I would look in to the red text in the screenshot you provided. Seems pretty likely to be your problem, given that it is red and says error.

Comment: @TimSeguine but it works on another machine ...

Comment: @user1992200 Did you build OpenCV yourself? you may be linking it incorrectly.

Comment: @user1992200 Because your build machine probably isn't missing those dependencies.

Comment: @JonathanMee no i have downloaded it from opencv repository

Comment: @TimSeguine the exe file is running on build machine as well as another target machine

Comment: @user1992200 That doesn't mean that the problem machine isn't missing dependencies. Find out what they are. Probably a specific redistributable. Your tool is telling you there is a problem, listen to your tool.

Comment: From the screenshot, for example, I can see that OpenCV appears to require the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679#) Since you haven't said which C++ redistributable you have installed I am going to assume you installed the one for your version of visual studio (2013). In this case, that wouldn't seem to be sufficient. It would probably be best to build opencv yourself to avoid this problem.

Comment: @Tim Seguine installing c++ redistributable  solved the problem...can you suggest any good tutorial for dependency walker...

Comment: @TimSeguine how can i create a installer for the vs build to run on any machine that did not have c++ redistributable installed.

Comment: I haven't used visual studio in quite a while.  I am not a good person to ask that.  I haven't ever even used dependency walker. All I did was read the information in the screenshot.  There is a lot of red stuff about missing implicit dependencies. I looked at the file list and saw a red box next to a vc redistributable that I guessed you hadn't installed. That's it. No magic,  just a little critical thinking. I already said: listen to your tools.  It works.

Comment: As for installing it on computers,  you are going to need some sort of installation generator to make things easier for yourself. I don't really know what any free options are that work on your target platform.  I could find an answer,  but you might as well Google it,  because that's all I would need to do.

Answer (score 0):

1)It is possible the new machine is missing important software like .NET framework or something similar. Please install the other frameworks and then try to run it on other machine.

2)If new machine has other OS try to run program in compatibility mode

Answer (score 0):

You need the same Visual Studio redistributable .dlls on your target machine.

You'll either need to install the redistributable or install visual studio on that machine.

Also note that it makes a difference whether you're using Express or not.

So you can't develop on Visual Studio 2008 Express and then install the Visual Studio 2008 Redistributable.

Comment: i have built the app using visual studio ultimate 2013 and the target machine has c++ redistribution package.